# Lean C development environment on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, gcc, development, c

I need a very lean system with minimum of packages installed for development in C programming language.

I know about `build-essential` meta-package but it's too big for my intents as I'm just working with C, not C++ etc.

I've tried to install just `gcc` but it still requires a lot of extra packages.
What is the best approach to get the bare minimum for C development of Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: What are the "lot of extra packages"?

Comment: Extra packages are: binutils cpp cpp-4.8 libasan0 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcloog-isl4 libgcc-4.8-dev libgmp10 libisl10 libitm1 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libquadmath0 libtsan0 linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install gcc --no-install-recommends  --no-install-suggests`. Some of those are definitely just recommended/suggested packages.

Comment: You don't know what [CPP](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html) is?